# Socket.IO Error while creating message recieve_listener

Tags: c++, socket.io

I am writing a program to communicate using Socket.IO with a NodeJS server. I have successfully connected to server and also have sent message to server. But I am getting error while creating a message receive_listener.

```
Error Statement :
this->current_socket->on("message", std::bind(&Socket_IO::receive_listener, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4));

void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const& name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::ptr &ack_resp)
{
    spdlog::info("Data Recieved : " + data->get_map()["message"]->get_string());
}
```

Code given above return the following error.

```
no instance of overloaded function "sio::socket::on" matches the argument list  
argument types are: (const char [8], std::_Binder<std::_Unforced, void (Socket_IO::*)(const std::string &name, const sio::message::ptr &data, bool hasAck, sio::message::ptr &ack_resp), Socket_IO *, const std::_Ph<1> &, const std::_Ph<2> &, const std::_Ph<3> &, const std::_Ph<4> &>)
            object type is: sio::socket

'void sio::socket::on(const std::string &,const sio::socket::event_listener_aux &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::_Binder<std::_Unforced,void (__cdecl Socket_IO::* )(const std::string &,const sio::message::ptr &,bool,sio::message::ptr &),Socket_IO *,const std::_Ph<1> &,const std::_Ph<2> &,const std::_Ph<3> &,const std::_Ph<4> &>' to 'const sio::socket::event_listener &'

tuple index out of bounds
```

O.S : Windows 10 Pro.

IDE : Visual Studio 15.9.7

C++ : C++17

Comment: You might want to check the documentation and examples (like e.g. [this example](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/examples/Console/main.cpp)).

Comment: I am referring their Handling Socket.IO Events from their example on main page : https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/

Comment: Reading [the API overview on GitHub](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp/blob/master/API.md) there seems to be two overloads of the `on` function. For some reason your call seems to be the one for the `event_listener_aux const&` argument. And for that you need to create a `event_listener_aux` object that you pass (e.g. `event_listener_aux(std::bind(...))` if I read my linked example correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by changing my Socket_IO::receive_listener defination

from

```
void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const& name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::ptr &ack_resp)
```

to

```
void Socket_IO::receive_listener(std::string const&name, sio::message::ptr const& data, bool hasAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp)
```

Even though the example uses `sio::message::ptr` data-type for `&ack_resp` after reading the header file I found out that the functional definition for event_listener_aux requires the callback definition to be

```
std::function<void(const std::string& name,message::ptr const& message,bool need_ack, message::list& ack_message)
```

It can be noted that `ack_message` requires `message::list&` data-type and not `message::ptr&` as mentioned in the example.